Error creating bean with name "webSecurityConfiguration" with spring data mongodb
I am using the "Spring Data MongoDB" persistence to develop an API with a backend connected to mongodb, the problem I have is when I want to create the repositories, because they ask me for something called mongoTemplate.
I'm using Domain Driven Design, so I need to be sorted on where each folder goes and what bounded context it belongs to.
No, I am NOT using MongoDBConfiguration, if that is the problem, please let me know, it is the first time I have made code using this and it would be very helpful to hear opinions from professionals :)
All my code
(Sorry, stackoverflow says is spam)
This is what my console says:
2024-09-24T16:42:01.290-05:00 ERROR 15020 --- [Roademics Platform] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration' defined in file [D:\Solutions_IntelliJ\upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API\target\classes\com\roademics\platform\upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi\iam\infrastructure\authorization\sfs\configuration\WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Solutions_IntelliJ\upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API\target\classes\com\roademics\platform\upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi\iam\infrastructure\authorization\sfs\services\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.roademics.platform.upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi.iam.infrastructure.persistence.sdmdb.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration' defined in file [D:\Solutions_IntelliJ\upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API\target\classes\com\roademics\platform\upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi\iam\infrastructure\authorization\sfs\configuration\WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Solutions_IntelliJ\upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API\target\classes\com\roademics\platform\upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi\iam\infrastructure\authorization\sfs\services\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.roademics.platform.upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi.iam.infrastructure.persistence.sdmdb.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\Solutions_IntelliJ\upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API\target\classes\com\roademics\platform\upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi\iam\infrastructure\authorization\sfs\services\UserDetailsServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.roademics.platform.upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi.iam.infrastructure.persistence.sdmdb.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: com/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory
    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: com/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception with message: com/mongodb/connection/StreamFactory


can you share your project structure and pom.xml files

dude, no way i finally solved it.
Basically i needed to change my java 22 to java 17, create a "MongoConfig" wich contained a mongoTemplate builder (i put it in shared/infrastructure/repositories/${persistence name}/config/MongoConfig).
Pom.xml:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>central</id>
   <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.3</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.roademics.platform</groupId>
 <artifactId>upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API</name>
 <description>upc-prep-202402-cc-238-WV61-WeHaveAnIdea-API</description>
 <url/>
 <properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <!-- Managed dependencies go here -->
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies>

  <!-- MongoDB Dependencies -->
  <!-- MongoDB starter for Spring Boot -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- MongoDB Driver -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Documentation Dependencies -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Lombok Dependency -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Security Dependencies -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-api -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
   <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
   <version>0.12.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-impl -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
   <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
   <version>0.12.3</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt-jackson -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
   <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
   <version>0.12.3</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.13</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Test Dependencies -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
   <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <excludes>
      <exclude>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </exclude>
     </excludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>



MongoConfig:


package com.roademics.platform.upcprep202402cc238wv61wehaveanideaapi.shared.infrastructure.persistence.sdmdb.configuration;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import jakarta.annotation.PreDestroy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        this.mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoUri);
        return this.mongoClient;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeMongoClient() {
        if (mongoClient != null) {
            mongoClient.close();
        }
    }
}



